# Elasticsearch delete new document in some index after save

Tags: elasticsearch

I have index that for a long time had saved 50 key value as 50 document. Now i am trying to save new key value. After sending save request and get acknowledge, i check content of index, there are new key and value. but after some minute the new document is deleted automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible that there is an [ILM policy](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-lifecycle-management.html) defined in your cluster that is automatically managing your indices and is deleting the data.

Comment: i deleted index and save all document again(old documents and new doc one). but again new doc had deleted.
Again, do you think it could be related to ILM policy?